What's the alternative of PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) after that is deprecated
When i am using this PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) (App Level) then we installed the new build , after installing the application open direct home page not ask for login page thats my issue , i tried many time but not get any solution.
i tried this  context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) [Global Level] but still not resolve my issue

A SharedPreferences are a persistent storage, meaning that the value you store there will be present across restarts and updates of the app.  To remove a value stored in the SharedPreferences, you need to either

clear the app data or
uninstall the app.

Please also note that the recommended way to store preferences is through the DataStore API. It is specialized for Kotlin and offers some other improvements.

Not really clear what you are trying to say. If your question is :
That you had a code which uses - PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
And the you build a deployable (APK or APK via Bundle or installed the APK directly through android studio) and then the login page is not coming.
MAYBE because your code is not supposed to login everytime. And the previous Preference for the App has not been cleared out. Delete the App and its storage.
Then try it.
